# How to Add Parameters to Existing NSMutableURLRequest with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, afnetworking, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a NSMutableURLRequest that has been created like so:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<my url>];
urlRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:<my method>
                                      path:<my uri>
                                parameters:<my parameters>];
```

At some point later in my program, I wish to append additional parameters to the `urlRequest` (while keeping **everything else unchanged**) before running the network operation. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to AFNetworking it returns a NSMutableRequest object.   ​

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

Now depending of the type of request you're doing `(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE)` you can access to the request parameter by:

GET:
request.URL.parameterString

POST:
request.HTTPBody

Comment: Right, but there is no convenient method in the AFNetworking library that allows for appending of parameters? I know I can dig in and do it myself, but I'd rather not if there already is a well-tested method written to do it.

Comment: I would suggest in that case create a mutableDictionary with a convenient method where it will create a new request with your parameters.